# systemctl not using full share path on boot

Tags: fstab, automounting, smb

I have a samba server that is running on my home router that I am attempting to connect to on system startup.

Importantly the router will automatically setup the share names for me and they are in the form `foo (at Elements)`

I have added an fstab entry to mount the samba share on my linux server and it works fine if i run the mount command directly ala `sudo mount /media/sambashare`

the fstab entry looks like so:

```
//192.168.50.1/andy\040\050at\040Elements\051  /media/samba_share  cifs  credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec,vers=2.0,gid=1002,uid=114,_netdev,x-systemd.requires=network.target 0 0
```

However whenever the system boots the drive is never mounted.

I've finally tracked down what seems to be the issue.

When i run `mount` manually i can find journalctl entries that look like so:

```
Jan 01 21:56:59 media-server sudo[5624]:   andymc : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/andymc ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mount /media/samba_share
Jan 01 21:56:59 media-server kernel: CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.50.1\andy (at Elements)
```

but on system startup the log entries look a bit different.

```
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server systemd[1]: Mounting /media/samba_share...
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server kernel: CIFS: Attempting to mount \\192.168.50.1\andy
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server kernel: CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -2
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server mount[1250]: mount error(2): No such file or directory
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server mount[1250]: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server systemd[1]: media-samba_share.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=32/n/a
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server systemd[1]: media-samba_share.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 01 21:51:03 media-server systemd[1]: Failed to mount /media/samba_share.
```

note how in the second log entry it doesn't include the `at Elements` bit in the sharename it attemptsto mount. I'm pretty sure that is what is causing this to fail but i can't figure out how to prevent it.

Any ideas?

Comment: "_When i run mount manually_" - what's the exact command you run? Do you even refer to `/etc/fstab` or do you just specify everything directly? If the latter, try `sudo mount /media/samba_share` instead

Answer (score 0):

Systemd is not using the contents of `/etc/fstab` directly, but running a `systemd-fstab-generator` to build mount units out of each non-empty non-comment line of the fstab file. (See `man 8 systemd-fstab-generator`, `man 5 systemd.mount`, and `man 7 systemd.generator` for details.)

The messages indicate that the escaped spaces and parentheses apparently don't survive this process, and the share name gets cut off after `\\192.168.50.1\andy`.

To see if the problem is caused by the `systemd-fstab-generator` process, you could comment out the `/etc/fstab` line for the share, and instead directly write a mount unit for it, as `/etc/systemd/system/media-samba_share.mount`:

```
[Unit]
Documentation=man:fstab(5)
After=network.target
Requires=network.target
Before=remote-fs.target

[Mount]
What=//192.168.50.1/andy\x20\x28at\x20Elements\x29
# if the above won't work, try this form:
# What=//192.168.50.1/andy (at Elements)
Where=/media/samba_share
Type=cifs
Options=credentials=/etc/samba/user,noexec,vers=2.0,gid=1002,uid=114

[Install]
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
```

Note that as described in `man systemd.unit`, systemd uses hexadecimal-based character escapes rather than legacy octal.

Actually it is possible that you might get away with not doing any escaping at all when writing your own custom mount unit like this. Try it that way if hex escapes don't work.

After creating the mount unit file, run `systemctl daemon-reload` to make the change effective, then run `systemctl start media-samba_share.mount` to test it. If it works now, it should also work at boot time.

Comment: this is working but doesn't run on boot. Service is inactive until i manually run it.

Comment: Oops, I forgot... add an `[Install]` section with a `WantedBy=remote-fs.target` at the end. I'll edit that in the answer too. By the way, was the working form the one with the hex escapes, or the one with no escapes at all?

Comment: This honestly sounds like a bug in systemd-fstab-generator; it's clearly capable of parsing the fstab entry with escapes in it, but is generating the wrong format for the .mount unit... I _think_ it might be because the function that parses `What=` was switched at some point (from reading it as a single value including spaces, to reading it as a space-separated list) and nobody updated the generator to match.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes, this is starting to look like a bug in `systemd-fstab-generator` in whatever distribution the OP is using, maybe they'd like to send in a bug report? Because there was no information about the distribution (and so no idea about the version of `systemd` used in it), I supplied the two variations of the `What=` line. Anyway, it looks like writing a custom `.mount` unit will be a valid workaround until the bug is fixed. However I'd blame the router manufacturer too: a share name like that is just asking for trouble, even with just older Windows software.